# call jquery plugin function from main page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, timeout

Hey all i am trying to find a way to add a call to pause this image slider. Currently it only pauses when you roll you mouse over the image. Once you roll off the image the slide show continues.

The start of the slider code is:

```
 ;(function($) {
$.fn.leanSlider = function(options) {

// Defaults
    var defaults = {
        pauseTime: 4000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        startSlide: 0,
        directionNav: '',
        directionNavPrevBuilder: '',
        directionNavNextBuilder: '',
        controlNav: '',
        controlNavBuilder: '',
        prevText: 'Prev',
        nextText: 'Next',
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        afterLoad: function(){}
    };

    var init = function() {

    // Set up pauseOnHover
        if(settings.pauseOnHover && settings.pauseTime && settings.pauseTime > 0){
            slider.hover(
                function () {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                },
                function () {
                    doTimer();
                }
            );
        }
   };

   //More code here....
 };    
})(jQuery);
```

I've been trying to call it from a onClick button like so:

```
$.fn.init.leanSlider.slider.clearTimeout();
```

But that just throws an error... What am i missing?

Comment: That is because `$.fn.init.leanSlider.slider.clearTimeout` does not exist...

Comment: because that plugin doesn't contains function/definition of clearTimeout.

Comment: you need a way to get `timer` from the plugin and then call `window.clearTimeout(timer);`